# Nginx - Broadcast request to all pods behind a kubernetes headless service

Tags: nginx, broadcast, kubernetes-service

I am running a nginx as a proxy for a k8s backend which has 2 instances running. A request sent to nginx is routed to only one pod as of now. My requirement is to route a request to all the pods behind the service. Is there any built in support in nginx for this type of broadcasting?

I tried with normal service and headless service. But the request is only routed to one pod.